# Retrieve RISC-V processor context after execution in FPGA

Tags: fpga, cpu-registers, microprocessors, riscv

I'm loading RISC-V into a Zedboard and I'm running a benchmark (provided in riscv-tools) without booting riscv-linux, in this case:

```
./fesvr-zynq median.riscv
```

It finishes without errors, giving as result the number of cycles and instret.

My problem is that I want more information, I would like to know the processor context after the execution (register bank values and memory) as well as the result given by the algorithm. Is there any way to know this from the FPGA execution? I know that it can be done with the simulator but I need to run it on FPGA.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the same way it gives you the `cycles` and `instret` data. Check out `riscv-tests/benchmarks/common/*`.  The code is running bare metal so you can write whatever code you want and access any of the CSRs, registers or memory, and then you can use a basic version of printf to display the information.